# svg change rectangle Color on button ng-click

Tags: angularjs, svg

i need to change svg rect color when i click on the button . i succedded to load svg  but i have a problem with  change color rect svg:

Controller.js:

```
angular.module('svgApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {       
        $scope.changeColor = function () {
            var places = element[0].querySelectorAll('.st2');
            $scope.places = "#fffd";           
        }
    }]);
```

widget.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="FrontEnd/Css/Style.css"/>
</head>
<body ng-app="svgApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1> Hello  My WidgetTest</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div svg-demo></div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <button ng-click="changeColor()" class="btn btn-block btn-default">ChangeColor</button>
    </p>


    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="FrontEnd/JS/Controller.js"></script>
    <script src="FrontEnd/JS/Directive.js"> </script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>


</body>
```

Comment: show the svg template

Comment: Hello, the svg file is big,

Comment: <g id="group43-72" transform="translate(67.3228,-318.898)" v:mID="43" v:groupContext="group">
   <title>PDP-E-EL.43</title>
   <g id="group44-73" v:mID="44" v:groupContext="group">
  <title>PDP-E00-01.91</title>
  <g id="shape45-74" v:mID="45" v:groupContext="shape"><title>Feuille.45</title>
<rect x="0" y="549.235" width="77.9528" height="46.0409" class="st2"/>
</g>