# angular js directives change Color svg element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I have successfully loaded a svg correctly. I want to change the color of the svg rect. I created this directive to do that but it doesn't work:

directives.js:

```
angular.module('svgApp').directive('place', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.elementId = element.attr("class");
            scope.placeClick = function () {
                scope.presskey(scope.elementId);
                alert(scope.elementId);
            };           
            element.attr("ng-click", "placeClick()");
            element.attr("ng-attr-fill", "yellow");
            element.removeAttr("place");
            $compile(element)(scope);

        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is `scope.presskey`? Can you give an example on plunker?

Comment: What's the difference between this question and your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009480/svg-change-rectangle-color-on-button-ng-click)

Comment: Hello, have you an idea please