# Change svg color on button click via typescript

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, svg

I want to change the fill color of my SVG when I do a button click. I am able to change it via external CSS(using npm package angular-svg-icon) but I don't know how to do this via typescript. I've encountered a similar question here in stackoverflow but no one has given an answer to the user: [svg change rectangle Color on button ng-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009480/svg-change-rectangle-color-on-button-ng-click)

**circle.svg:**

```
<svg id="bars" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 63.15 224.35">
    <circle class="cls-1" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="#529fca" />
</svg>
```

**tab1.page.html:**

```
<ion-content>
    <svg-icon [applyCss]="true" src="assets/images/circle.svg" [svgStyle]="{ 'height.px':200, 'width.px':200 }" />
    <ion-button (click)="ChangeColor()">Click</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

**tab1.page.scss:**

```
#bars{
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}

.cls-1 {
    fill:blue;
}
```

function where I plan to manipulate the SVG color: `ChangeColor(){   }`

Comment: Why not to use `style="fill:red;"` and change `red` to color you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can add conditional [class](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) on your svg and apply css for fill something like

```
<circle  [ngClass]="{'someclassname': yourconditionvariable}"></circle>
```

in css

```
.someclassname{
      //your css to fill the color
}
```

then in changecolor method set `yourconditionvariable` to true

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9uwzc)

Comment: this worked when the svg is created inside the html page but when I reference it via `src="assets/images/circle.svg"` in `<svg-icon>`, the color change no longer works.

Comment: you can't modify svg in this way